# How to get a sum of occurrences of the IP addresses found in access.log

Tags: nginx, awk, grep

I am trying to get the number of the specific occurrences of the IP addresses found in nginx access.log.
The access.log format is as follows

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [21/Dec/2021:12:59:30 +0100] "GET /<some/path/on/webserver>" 200 1028 "<referrer>" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 11; SM-A202F) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.104 Mobile Safari/537.36" "-"
```

The awk which I'm currently using is

```
awk '$7 ~ /^\/rest\/default\/V1\/products-render-info?/ {print $1, $5}' /var/log/nginx/access.log.1 | sort -u > test.txt
```

And the result saved in text file is, with only unique IP addresses,

```
127.0.0.1 
/rest/default/V1/products-render-info?searchCriteria.... <snip>
```

However, I would like to know the number occurrences of the IP addresses as well something like

```
127.0.0.1
<number of times this IP address has been found in the access.log>
/rest/default/V1/products-render-info?searchCriteria.... <snip>
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
grep "^[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+" test.txt | awk -F" " '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c
```

??? Pardon me?

Well, let's start with the regular expression:

```
^       : beginning of line
[0-9]\+ : a list of digits (at least one)
\.      : a dot
```

So, your line should start with a beginning of line (obvious), then a list of at least one digit, a dot, ... and this four times (but without the dot at the end).

Like this you have found your IP addresses.

Then you parse that, using a space as a field seperator (`awk -F" "`), and you show the first column `'{print $1}'`.

Now you have shown a list of IP addresses, which you would want to count.

Therefore you first sort them (`sort`) and once you're finished, the count the unique results (`uniq -c`).

Easy, isn't it? :-)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, test.txt file contains only unique IP addresses and requests. What I wanted is to count them in the access.log, and write them to test.txt with number of occurrences... Like `awk '$7 ~ /^\/rest\/default\/V1\/products-render-info?/ {print $1, $5}' /var/log/nginx/access.log.1 | sort | uniq -c > test.txt` which looks like what I wanted to begin with... Basically "show me the sum of all IP addresses occurrences, where the request URL begins with /rest/default/V1/products-render-info and save them to test.txt"